# Compose: LazyVerticalGrid with variable contentPadding

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to display a `LazyVerticalGrid` with three columns. At the top, I want a header that spans all columns and scrolls with the content. This works fine using an `item` at the beginning that sets the `span` to `maxLineSpan`.

However, I want the main content of the grid to have a `contentPadding` of 16 dp. At the same time, the header is supposed to be full-bleed, i.e. the `contentPadding` should not apply to the header.

What is the best way to achieve this with `LazyVerticalGrid`? Manually adding start/end padding to the content items based on the column they're in seems to be not an option, as the width of the item in the middle doesn't scale proportionally.

Comment: Just an idea. What if you increase span size and add extra dummy items as spacer?

Comment: @Sky that might work, thanks! – still wondering if there's a less hacky solution.

Comment: @HannesStruß did you find a way to set the padding separately for each span?